# Laravel 5 SQLSTATE[23000] users_email_unique

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5

I am implementing a social authentication on my website with laravel 5.

I successfully logged in a couple of users but now for some very strange reasons it doesn't work anymore..

When I try to log in a new user I have this error coming up:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 624:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `profile_picture`, `facebook_id`) values (Hwan, https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/1701160536770162/picture1701160536770162type=normal, ?))
```

But this user has never been registered in the DB before !!

I tried with other users, all the same...

But if I remove an existing FB user from the DB and try again, it works !!

Here is my controller:

```
class AccountController extends Controller {
/**
 * Redirect the app to the social provider
 *
 * @return SNS token and user data
 */
public function redirectToProvider($provider) {
    return Socialize::with($provider)->redirect();
}
/**
 * Callback handler
 *
 * @return redirect to index
 */
public function handleProviderCallback($provider) {
    $user   = Socialize::with($provider)->user();

    // get the sns user data
    $id         = $user->getId();
    $name   = $user->getName();
    $avatar = $user->getAvatar();

    // get the user provider id form the DB
    $users = DB::table('users')->where($provider.'_id', $id)->get();

    // check if the record exists
    if(empty($users)){
        DB::table('users')->insert(
            ['name' => $name,'profile_picture' => $avatar,$provider.'_id' => $id]
        );
        $users = DB::table('users')->where($provider.'_id', $id)->get();
    }

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        $userID = $user->id;
    }
    Auth::loginUsingId($userID);
    {
        return redirect()->to('home');
    }
}
```

}

And my routes:

```
Route::get('connect/{provider}', 'AccountController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('account/{provider}', 'AccountController@handleProviderCallback');
```

And my user schema:

```
 Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('profile_picture');
        $table->text('facebook_id');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a unique constraint on your email field but you do not appear to be inserting an email address. After one user is inserted without an email address, no other users can be signed up without an email address.

You will not be able to have two empty strings in the email column of your database.

Comment: Wow I haven't thought that with that unique field, having 2 empty fields is not possible.... Is there a way to exclude empty field from that constraint ?

Comment: I mark your answer as solved. But any recommendations about those empty fields are welcomed :) Thank you !!

Comment: _“Is there a way to exclude empty field from that constraint ?”_ – for that, you’d have to check for the value being an empty string in your code, and replace it with NULL instead. (And make sure that the column allows NULL values.)